# Is it rude to ask a coworker about their starting salary

Tags: professionalism, salary

I am currently a college student in between my Junior and Senior years.  A classmate of mine recommended me to his company for an internship and I am now working for said company as a summer intern.  The classmate, and now coworker, works in this office occasionally but usually works from home.

It is fairly likely that this company may offer me a full time position after this internship.  Since the classmate and I have similar backgrounds, I am curious how much this company offered him for salary when he was initially hired.  Is it impolite to ask about that sort of thing?

Comment: Note that unless the other person started recently, at the same site, with the same kind of responsibilities, and in the same kind of competitive market, the answer may not actually tell you anything useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It is fairly likely that this company may offer me a full time
>   position after this internship. Since the classmate and I have similar
>   backgrounds, I am curious how much this company offered him for salary
>   when he was initially hired. Is it impolite to ask about that sort of
>   thing?

"Impolite" is in the eye of the beholder. Some folks would be embarrassed or offended by being put in the position of disclosing their salary. Others wouldn't.

Without knowing your classmate personally, nobody here can tell if he would consider your request impolite or not.

You can approach this in a few ways that might avoid some embarrassment.

If you are close enough, you could be forthright and ask something like "I think I'm going to be offered a full-time position soon. Any idea what would be a reasonable salary to expect?" That way you are drawing on his knowledge about what he got, without actually asking him his starting salary.

Or, you could wait until you get an offer, then ask for his opinion as to reasonableness. "I was just offered $X. Based on your experience here, is that a good starting salary, or should I be asking for more?" Again, you are getting his insight, but not asking for his prior or current salary.

Comment: This sounds reasonable. I know it varies from person to person, but I wasn't sure if this sort of question might be some sort of taboo. This is answer was very helpful though, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I find the best way to ask is not to ask what he is making specifically, but rather what they typically pay starting. (it's almost the same question but it helps because instead of feeling obligated to answer 37,500$ he can say 35-40K) For you that's actually more useful since what you'll be offered will depend on your background and negations so will likely be different.

Comment: Right, I am definitely more interested in where he started than what he is currently making.